# Found a co-worker on a dating website. How do I approach them?

Tags: relationships

I found a co-worker on a dating site. I've seen her around before but have never spoken and never really had any interest.

However, after reading her profile, I am interested in pursuit, but am not sure of the appropriateness:

1. The dating site charges a high fee. I'm not super comfortable paying to message just one person. Would it be considered harassment if I messaged them directly at work? (I'd find this creepy myself so probably yes?). If it is I'd just pay the fee.
2. Would it be considered harassment and a risk to my career if I approached her on the dating website? Both of us are aware the other works at the company

I should note that I'm aware of the "don't defecate where you work" idiom and how bad things can get dating a co-worker. In my case I feel that doesn't apply - we're not even in the same building, and it's a huge company.

Comment: Why didn't you include your country??

Comment: Do you find it creepy to ask the other person out without mentioning the Website?

Comment: Is "liking" her or "swiping right" an option on this website? If both of you "swipe right" and it's a match, then it would be more appropriate to approach her via the website, I'd say. Approaching her at work wouldn't be correct.

Comment: @guest considering they have never spoken before, I think anyone would consider it creepy.

Comment: How reliable is the site? Does the profile state where she works? How careful is she with her pictures online? Is it possible to rule out that the site made a fake account and it's just coincidence that they found her picture online for the profile?

Comment: @Charmander Great idea, although I think if you "match" or something, it should already be fine to approach her at work instead, assuming she was aware that OP is a coworker

Comment: `In my case I feel that doesn't apply - we're not even in the same building, and it's a huge company.` - The fact that you've "seen her around before" makes this comment irrelevant. The mere possibility of running into someone she declined on a dating site may create a hostile work environment for her. That is not fair to her regardless of the size of the company.

Comment: You should also think twice about dating a co-worker. If it doesn't work, you risk awkward situations on a daily basis.

Comment: "Pursuit"? What century are you in?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

> Found a co-worker on a dating website. How do I approach them?

You approach them through the dating site.  On the dating site she is presumably open to being approached by other people, at work that might not be the case.  If the fee on the site is too much then do not bother pursuing her at all.  The money lost for being fired for harassment will probably be much greater than the dating site fee.

Comment: Is it really *that* bad in your country (or at big international companies) nowadays? An employee having a profile on a dating website will file for harassment and make a coworker fired if approached and asked out in a respectful manner? Is asking someone out politely (without pressuring if the answer is "no") considered **harassment** now?

Comment: @Val if he approaches her at any other way besides the dating site it might be. If he messages her on the dating she might ignore him. Maybe she isn't even using the dating site anymore because she already found someone.

Comment: @Val I agree with you, but that's how it is at the moment. And I think OP should be careful since it's workplace related.

Comment: This feels a bit overly paranoid, though it would be nice to have the country the OP is in, but it's hard to see how asking someone out would be considered harassment by anyone. How did people ever get together before dating sites?

Comment: @val welcome to the XXI century. I heard a psychologist describing what's happening now as "Social Inflammation" - Inflammation as in the medical symptom.

Comment: @Val I find the harassment argument is born out of extreme cases made popular. Like you shouldn't tramp because you can get snatched by a serial killer. Yeah, it can happen, but the likelihood is pretty slim*. Still, it's not appropriate to just assume she has interest in you because you found her on the dating site. The dating site is a separate context - and she might just decline your contact attempt there which saves face for everyone. If you mess up the "asking nice" at work, you made it a work place issue and mixed quite personal with work boundaries. Many people don't like that.

Comment: Plus she might reject you just for bringing her private life to work. Especially if it's a "special interest" dating website.
*at least in most (first world?) countries.

Comment: Maybe the picture is not the person who owns the profile on the dating site? After all, is it unknown for people to falsify information on the internet?

Comment: Could you, sf02, and also you, @Jungkook state the countries where a polity asking out would be seen as harassment?

Comment: @guest In the USA asking someone out at work can be seen as harassment.  All it takes is someone feeling uncomfortable, reporting the incident,  and an over-zealous HR to cause harm to someone's career.  The risk does not outweigh the reward in my opinion, and it is unprofessional behavior.  There are plenty of non-work settings to pursue romantic interests.

Comment: @guest is doesn't depend on the country, it depends on the person being asked's view of the person asking. (In how I met your mother it's called the [dahmer-dobler theory](https://how-i-met-your-mother.fandom.com/wiki/The_Dobler-Dahmer_Theory) )

Comment: @Jungkook: I mainly refer to someone taking the harassment claim so serious that OP would be in trouble (the answerer writes about getting fired). USA must truly be a sad country, in this regard..

Comment: @guest if HR takes it serious and there is an investigation (that turns out negative) it may damage OP's career while being innocent.

Comment: @Jungkook: I agree but it is hard to believe that HR takes it serious anywhere except in the US.

Comment: @guest it depends on how much of a fuzz someone makes and on the HR person

Comment: @Jungkook : Is it that bad in the USA? If I want to ruin the life of a coworker out of spite (or just because I'm bored) I could just go to HR, complain of sexual harassment even if nothing happened, and the coworker's career will be damaged even if there is no proof for my allegations?

Comment: @Val it might be yeah, in some cases you will be in trouble for falsely accusing your coworker. You don't know unless it happens to you

Comment: I'd add this: OP should put themselves in the shoes of this coworker. By using the dating site they can introduce themselves far more comprehensive and they give this coworkerthe time and leisure to have a good look and think before she agrees to a date or exchanges messages (depending, of ocurse, on how much trouble OP will put into their profile and what kind of profile this site encourages)

Comment: @Val it is not that bad that contacting someone leads to a sexual harassment claim, but it can end there depending on how you approach it way easier than if you contact the same person via a dating platform where she's explicitly registered an account and therefore is open in general to be approached. In general, you can be way more direct via the page and stay within "proper bounds" than with a direct approach at work. Going in for a direct approach skips steps you'd otherwise do when you do online dating and you do it in a professional environment with higher chances for both to loose face.

Comment: @Val the answer simply shortens the comparison of potential cost risk vs pretty low risk/fixed cost. Potential reactions and repercussions with a direct approach are simply much wider and harder to gauge and include more extreme outcomes (with very low probability if you're not an ass) than if you go via online dating. If you want to do it "proper" via direct contact at work, you'd need to do it slow -> also more costly than jumping in more directly at the dating site (time is money).

Comment: "Hi I've seen you on that Dating platform", that would be a really strange opener. It immediately brings up the question why you didn't contact person X on the platform. Then if you say "I wanted to save the money" you just look cheap. Nah if you have a good feeling with that person spend the money write something nice, stay respectful and respect her boundaries (as you always should). Only ever bring it up at work after a successful first date and only in private.

Comment: @seg "that would be a really strange opener" I don't think so, as long as you're not being a creep about it. "then if you say "I wanted to save the money" you just look cheap." Sure, but if you say something like "I already know you in real life, and talking to you like this is so much better, right?" probably wouldn't be too bad.

Comment: @nick012000 I suppose it could be seen that way depends on the person. Still I think most people wouldn't like being put on the spot like that. Saying "I've seen you online on that dating platform" would imply a lot of hidden expectations and could be very uncomfortable for the other person. If you want to introduce yourself at work I probably wouldn't mention the dating site at all.

Answer (score 35):

In my view, the dating website is a red herring. Why not approach the person directly at work (without mentioning the dating site) as you would normally ask out someone?  Whether this is considered harassment is dependent on your culture/locale (but when people become a couple in real life, someone has to ask out the other person!). In Southern Europe, it would be fine to ask out a person in your workplace with which you do not work together (of course, provided that you do this respectfully and with your employer's policy on that matter in mind).
Most couples do meet at work.

Of course, read in the Internet the usual advice for dating on the workplace. You can find a lot on that in the Internet.

And, just to be sure: it is usually better to ask one out personally than to message them (especially if this would be through a company channel), of course.

Comment: "it would be fine to ask out a person in your workplace with which you do not work together" - The author does work with this person, do what is your advice, if that is the case?

Comment: @Donald OP specifies that they do not work in the same building and implies they do not interact at work.

Comment: @Donald: They do not work together but work in the same company (say, a office worker and a janitor in different buildings, but payed by the same boss).

Comment: @dbeer work location is largely irrelevant depending on the company and job. I've worked in companies where my direct superior was situated in a building on the other side of the country and we only ever met once or twice a year except through email and/or phone calls. I've also worked in companies where I had a desk in the same room as the CEO.

Comment: I say find some plausible excuse to interact in some way at work and see if this person is someone you would even be interested in getting to know further. Pros: you know she is a real person, and know her actual appearance.  Cons: It's the workplace. I personally avoid all dating of coworkers, well, except for that one night stand. I got lucky and she's still a friend.  Anyway, IF your interaction reveals positive qualities and potential mutual compatibility and interest, you can decide where to take it from there, whether to approach via the dating site or in person.

Comment: I'd like to upvote this (I married someone from my workplace who asked me out), but making the approach __at work__ is not the right place to do it. Find a pub that everyone goes to after work, or something like that, and do it there. Not actually during work hours.

Comment: "it would be fine to ask out a person in your workplace" - **if** you've actually spoken a bit with this person before (which may or may not be in the same conversation). Simply asking out a stranger with no build-up would be weird at work as well as everywhere else.

Comment: BAD idea. For a litany of reasons. Had to downvote, sorry.

Comment: @PlayerOne: I do see your point. I do think the appropriatness of this varies between different locales and white/blue collar jobs. But in all cases, asking at the work place is not the optimal solution.

Comment: @gburton: No problem. But I would find it great if you could state the reasons (or what exactly you are objecting to.)

Comment: Making her work awkward is one issue. But the big one is that by using a dating site she is creating an environment where she is comfortable being contacted in a controlled manner, and having control over who she deals with - in person this falls away.

Comment: @gburton: In the US, maybe. Probably everywhere else people get asked out all the time at all situation and wihld not be uncomfortable if done respectfully and when a "no" is accepted.

Comment: The question is not culture specific so I would err on the side of caution.

Comment: @gburton In USA it's a no-go, in most countries in Europe it's no problem at all (as long as you're not her/ his boss).

Comment: @Chris that depends in Europe also on what and how you want to go at it and where in Europe you are. If she's in a different department and barely knows you directly asking for a date will come across as quite awkward in the European workplaces I know (central, north). Slowly getting to know her as a colleague, start having chats at work, slowly growing this into more and then eventually maybe go on a date, yeah that might work and is acceptable (as long as you recognize her potential signals of no interest), but then this takes way longer for a concrete result than another approach.

Comment: @Chris but even within countries there can be different cultural norms. If you're sure if your local norms and/or observe people around you behaving one way, then sure, go for that, but if you don't the online dating site would be the safer option.

Comment: @FrankHopkins We agree there, it is culture-specific. I was looking at it from employer perspective. Most companies in Europe don't care about it and normally it won't have any work related consequences. Still it's awkward for the people involved in it.

Answer (score 25):

**Don't do this...**

> The dating site charges a high fee. I'm not super comfortable paying to message just one person. Would it be considered harassment if I messaged them directly at work? (I'd find this creepy myself so probably yes?). If it is I'd just pay the fee.

Your gut instinct is good on this one. It would be extremely inappropriate to bring up the fact she's on the dating site in conversation - let alone actually acting on it to ask her out. She's using the dating site **outside** of work, not during.

More simply, even if you got the information that she's potentially looking for a partner via the dating site; sending anything like this during work, especially via work communication, is completely unsolicited and inappropriate.

> Would it be considered harassment and a risk to my career if I approached her on the dating website? Both of us are aware the other works at the company

No and Yes.

Would it be considered harassment? If you work nowhere near her, have no ties to her or her department, and were careful to respect her boundaries (as you should be anyway); then it'd be *unlikely* to escalate into a harassment claim (not impossible though).

Is it a good idea? Not really. You might not work together right now, but you don't know where you'll be (or where she'll be) in the next year. Even if you're completely unfazed by working with somebody you wanted to date - she might not be.

---

I'd strongly recommend you treat your current workplace as the biggest compatibility red-flag you can. If in all other aspects you think you might be interested in her; hold the fact you work together against it - it's not worth the risk.

It's not romantic to consider; but the reality is she is no more likely to be "the one" than the many other potential romances you might pursue. All good relationships are built over time, without ever being a perfect fit. Ignoring that you ever saw her profile is not going to hurt your chance to have a romantically fulfilling life - but it will do a lot to protect your career.

Comment: I would definitely hope she does get a say in whether they date or not.

Comment: @guest That was meant in the sense of her not getting a say in being asked; which may make the workplace less comfortable for her. I've removed the line as I can see how it reads the way you pointed out, and the sentiment is already in another part of the answer. (Thanks for pointing out the ambiguity)

Comment: @guest if he is in a higher grade position in the company than she is, she may feel pressured into accepting his advances for fear of rejecting having a negative influence on her career. (this can happen irrespective of the sex of the person holding the more superior position btw.

Comment: @jwenting: Theoretically, yes. But I think OP has to figure that out if that could be reasonably the case. My sister is a professional translator, her husband a janitor in another building of the company she is working at. I don't see any problem or pressure in this situation.

Answer (score 4):

One big problem is that just because you found *her photo* in a dating site doesn’t mean *she* is on the dating site. So if you approach her outside the website, it may be complete news to her that she is on that site, which might end up highly embarrassing for everyone. The more attractive she is (to someone who is looking for romance and is wise enough to know that supermodels are not on these websites), the more likely that it is a fake.

Especially when you are charged significant amounts of money for contact information.

PS Naive commenter doesn’t know how this works. He signs up, he pays, and lots of lovely women on the site unfortunately just found a partner and are not available anymore. That’s when the site is scamming. The other possibility is that a scammer signed up, numbers are estimated 25%. Does she have photos on Facebook? Open season for scammers.

Comment: This is not a "big" problem.  Unless the coworker is actually a model, the odds of somebody else randomly using their social photos are extremely low, particularly on a dating website where people expect to meet the other party in person.

Comment: You are very naive.

Comment: Oh, it's well known that fake profiles are a big thing on paid dating sites, but using the photos of actual people *in the same location* without permission has lawsuit written all over it.  Sure, an individual scammer might not care, but the site management themselves won't be this foolish.

Comment: How would they know it’s the same location? And if it’s a scammer, how would she find them?

Answer (score -1):

Short answer is that you don't.  There are old sayings:

"Don't dip your pen in the company ink"

"Don't fish off the company pier"

While the getting's good in such a relationship, if it goes bad, you have to see that person every day.  There's a high likelihood of HR intervening in your life, in a bad way.

Don't do it.

Comment: This answer is very culture specific. Maybe this is the case in the US but not in the UK.

Comment: Nope, in the UK too. Don't approach people at work for romantic relationships. It's totally inappropriate.